# confusion in implementing stack functions in stl

Tags: c++, function, stl, stack

```
#include<string>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stack>
using namespace std;


  int main() {
  int q;
   string s;
  stack <string> a;
  int z=0;

  cin>>q;
 while(q)
 {
  int t;
  cin>>t;

    string m;
    string n;
    string x;
    string l;

  a.push(s);
    int k;
    int z;
    switch(t)
    {
        case 1:
            //append


            cin>>x;
            s.append(x);
            //cout<<s<<endl;
            x.clear();
            a.push(s);
        cout<<a.top()<<endl;
            break;

        case 2:

       // cout<<s;
            // delete
            n=s;
            cin>>k;
           //cout<<s;
            while(k>0)
            {
                s.pop_back();
                k--;
            }
            a.push(s);
            cout<<a.top()<<endl;

            break;
        case 3:
            //print
        l=a.top();
            cin>>k;
                cout<<l[k-1]<<endl;
                l.clear();
            break;
            case 4:
            //undo
a.pop();
cout<<a.top()<<endl;


            break;

      }
 --q;}
 return 0;
 }
```

POP function doesnt seem to work properly as for following input

```
8
1 abc
3 3
2 3
1 xy
3 2
4 
4 
3 1
```

after inserting `xy` onto stack the undo operation pops the stack but top is always `xy` after it how? and why?
one more thing if i declare string `s` and string a inside while loop then the program doesn't run and gives segmentation fault,why?

Comment: And when you used your debugger to step through your code, one line at a time, examining the values of all variables, and observing the control flow, what conclusions did you make? The answer to your question is, simply: learn how to use a debugger. This is what a debugger is for. Knowing how to effectively use a debugger is a mandatory skill for every C++ developer.

Comment: i never used a debugger sorry i will learn it right now, thank you! it would be appreciated if you help me this one time though,

Comment: @coderredoc i am sorry sir but to my knowledge the above program is in c++ only

Comment: I didn't downvote. Try to use debugger. And yes the tag is edited.

Comment: @VivekChawla 1) Using debugger isn't as hard as you might think. You just start using it. 2) Using debugger, is essentially what anyone, who tries to solve your problem, will have to use anyways. So, why don't you cut out the middleman, by using it yourself?

Comment: on it already sir !

Comment: Or you could just add more output statements that tell you what's happening at each stage of the program.

Comment: Thank you all for introducing me to debugger it will save alot of my time ! i solved the above problem as well ! @coderredo